# Why isn't my import being found by the esm loader?

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, node-modules

I have a small express server and in my `bin/www.ts` I import my app.ts file like this:

```
import app from '../app';
```

When I build my project and turn it into JavaScript using: `tsc --project ./`
and then run it with `nodemon ./build/bin/www` I get an error in my console saying:

```
internal/process/esm_loader.js:74
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: 
Cannot find module '/Users/t86b/Desktop/Dev/Projects/TestServerProject/Server/build/app' 
imported from /Users/t86b/Desktop/Dev/Projects/TestServerProject/Server/build/bin/www.js
```

The file exists in the location I specified, I've checked and I've added the `"type":"module"` to my `package.json` file as well. I've removed every require from the app.ts file as well and still nothing yet. I'm not sure what to do at this point. Here is my `package.json` file (condensed to get to the point):

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc --project ./",
    "start": "nodemon ./build/bin/www",
    "start:dev": "nodemon -r ./bin/www.ts",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsStart": "node ./build/bin/www"
  },
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "typescript": "^4.0.3"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1"
  }
}
```

My `ts.config`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {   
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["ES2017"],  
    "outDir": "./build",
    "rootDir": "./",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node", 
    "esModuleInterop": true, 
    /* Advanced Options */
    "skipLibCheck": true, 
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true   
  }
}
```

If it helps, here is my app.ts, which also has no errors (condensed for clarity):

```
import express from 'express';
import indexRouter from './routes/index';
...
let app = express();
app.use('/', indexRouter);

export default app;
```

How do I get my project to see my file so that I can start up my server? thanks in advance and let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: in esm, the [file extension is mandatory](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_mandatory_file_extensions) (for relative imports).

Comment: that fixed it thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ASDFGerte pointed out that in esm you have to [include the file's extension for relative imports](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_mandatory_file_extensions). So I was able to fix and run my code by changing:
`import app from '../app';` to `import app from '../app.js';`